# Getting Azure Applications by subscription

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm using the Az modules in Powershell. I want to get the applications for my subscription ID.
Get-Context shows the SubscriptionID I want.

Get-AzAdApplication returns all of the applications for my company, 600K+ of them.
There doesn't seem to be any effective filtering on Get-AzAdApplication. The predecessor was Get-AzureAdApplication or Get-AzureRmAdApplication.

My goal is to scan the App registrations and validate the expiration of each of the service principals.
I need the ApplicationID to do that, but I can't seem to limit the query except by number of items returned. I don't really want to crawl through 600K applications.

Any idea if there is a way to proceed?

Comment: Do you have any other limitations of the query?

Comment: According to my view there is no relation between the subscription and your applications.  You should query all applications in your tenant and get the application id and then after use Get-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId 35157fe1-6ce8-47f6-9ea8-4d23afd4381d command. You can also use MS Graph to get the expiration date, appid using the below serviceprincipal endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals?$select=appid,keyCredentials.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between the subscription and your applications. You should query all applications in your tenant and get the application id and then after use `Get-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId 35157fe1-6ce8-47f6-9ea8-4d23afd4381d` command. You can also use MS Graph to get the expiration date, appid using the below serviceprincipal endpoint.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals?$select=appid,keyCredentials
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Get-AzADApplication doesn't have a parameter for the tenant. I know I can process in smaller pieces, but it still seems like I have to walk through all 600K returns to find what shows up in the portal.

Comment: Yes, we need to go through each and every tenant and apply the Get-AzADApplication because there is no link between subscription and applications in App registrations.